# Having 10 percent of the population left-handed was an advantage for human beings

Tags: grammar, word-order

> Having 10 percent of the population left-handed was an advantage for human beings.

Is the sentence above natural to you, especially, the part "Having 10 percent of the population left-handed".

Does the word order "10 percent of the population left-handed" make sense to you?

PS
I have realized that "having" is a gerund, and I do not have any problem about it. I am wondering about the phrase "10 percent of the population left-handed". Why is it possible? Is it possible because of "have"?

Comment: It could be worded better, perhaps, but it makes more sense than "Is the sentence above is natural to you".

Comment: @Hot Licks Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited.

Comment: I would change “the population” to “ **its/their** population,” and depending on the point of (and reasoning behind) the statement, I’d add “ **only** 10 percent.”  Otherwise it looks fine to me, although I might have written: “**That** [only] 10 percent of the/[its/their] population **was** left-handed proved [to be] advantageous for human beings.”

Comment: Think of the sentence in question as being a telescoped form of this wording: "Having [a situation in which] 10 percent of the [human] population [was] left-handed was an advantage for human beings."

Comment: Maybe it would be clearer if you imagined a missing "be" between "population" and "left-handed": "Having 51 percent of the population [be] female was an excellent idea." Depending on the context, the "missing" verb wouldn't have to be "be": "Having the cast of "Hair" [appear] nude increased ticket sales."

Comment: I think that *having* is altogether the wrong word to use, especially to start this sentence. Strictly it is idiomatic, and grammatical - but awfully laboured. My way of saying it would be *The fact of 10% of the population being left-handed has been an advantage to the human race*.

Answer (score 1):

*Having...* sounds very natural. Without it you have two structures as adjectives, "10 percent of" and "left-handed". Without *having*, the sentence does not have the ground.

On the other hand, "10 percent of the population was left-handed", is natural.

To place an adjective after such a long construction *10 percent of the population*, where another adjective is on the left is just not leading the sentence anywhere.

The compressed structure itself "10 percent of the population left-handed!" is very common in titles. "10 percent of gold bought!" "10 percent of rivers frozen!" and as you can see the adjective bought, frozen has kind of verb role,  they are holding action as if it is written: "10 percent of rivers freezes!"

In order to avoid this and similar confusions, you need something before the entire structure, like *having*, to make it all clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes perfect sense.  It's a gerund phrase.

When you say "having" in this context, you are using the present participle "having" as a gerund.  A gerund is the noun form of a verb.

By taking the gerund "having" and adding the phrase "10 percent of the population" after it, you are making what is called a [gerund phrase](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerundphrase.htm), which functions as a noun.  You are saying, "[It] was an advantage for human beings."  What was an advantage for human beings?  "Having 10 percent of the population left-handed" was an advantage for human beings.

It's absolutely correct and proper English.

Comment: Thank you, Benjamin Harman, What I want to know is: Can the verb "have" take two components "10%... and left-handed? Or what is the relation between 10%... and left-handed, though I agree with you about gerund. I do not have any problem about it

Comment: @243 : I'm not sure what you mean by "two components," but whatever you mean, the answer still is: no you can't.  "Having" isn't being used as a verb; it's being used as a noun.  There is no verb there, so something that isn't there can't have two components.  Remember, the subject is the nounal phrase "having 10 percent," which means it's not a verb.  "Having 10 percent" as a noun is adjectivally modified by the prepositional phrase "of the population."  The prepositional phrase has two components: "of," the preposition, and "the population," the object of the preposition.

Comment: "Have" can take one object. If "10 %..." is the object of the "have", what is "left-handed"? A  complement? Or Is the phrase from 10% to left-handed an object.

Comment: "Have" as a verb can take an object, but the gerund "having" as a noun can't take an object.  Nouns don't take objects.  In order to take an object, "having" would have to be being used as a verb, but it's not being used as a verb.  It's being used as a noun, so it has no object.  The gerund "having" itself could be an object, but it isn't an object in this sentence because it's the subject.

Comment: Having is no longer a verb. I get that. However, the gerund phrase "having 10 percent of the population left-handed" comes from the usage of the verb "have". In other word, you could probably say that human beings have 10 percent of the population left-handed. Then you could transform the sentence to gerund "having..."